# How do I keep the option selected when it changes and I need to reload the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="band_id" name="band_id">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Choose a band...</option>
  <option value="66">Adolfo Little</option>
  <option value="96">Aisha Bosco</option>
  <option value="90">Alize Glover</option>
</select>
```

I need to build a filter where the condition is the `#band_id` selected so I made this jQuery code:

```
$("select#band_id").change(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var band_id = $('select#band_id');

    if (band_id.val() != undefined) {
        band_id.attr('selected', 'selected');
    }

    location.href = '/albums/bands/' + band_id.val();
});
```

Because the `location.href` the page gets reloaded and the URL changes so the SELECT is reset and I "loose" the selected value.

I can think in two ways to fix this:

- Using AJAX which I don't want because is over complicate something easy
- Grab the band_id from the URL and then set the selected property which I don't know how to achieve.

I don't know is there any other way to achieve this. Do you have any other idea? (if it's with an example better)

Comment: You could use cookies but I would personally go with ajax. Since you are using jquery, it should just be one call targetting a div

Comment: cookie or localStorage are other alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for that:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("band_id")) {
    $("select#band_id").val(localStorage.getItem("band_id"))
}  
$("select#band_id").change(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).val() != undefined) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        localStorage.setItem("band_id", $(this).val());
    }

    location.href = '/albums/bands/' + $(this).val();
});
```

If we have the value saved - set the value of the `select` element to that values.
Once we change the value in the `select` element - save the new value in the localStorage.

> Note that I removed the usage of the `band_id` from this example as it's not needed. You have `this` you can use inside the `change` function.
>
> I'm also not sure why you change the `selected` attribute - you redirect the user immediately to a new page (this change will have no effect at all).

Comment: what is the `selected` for? That's for `<option>` not `<select>`

Comment: It's from the OP's question. I kept it there because he might need it for something else, but there is a not regarding it.

Comment: @Dekel great & clean example!!!, didn't worked before with `localStorage`. Thank you so much I learn something new :)

Comment: @ReynierPM will appreciate a vote-up on the answer as well :) Thanks!

Comment: @Dekel you've it before ask :) as I said I like to vote up when I learn something new and got a clean answer :)

Comment: oh :) haha. I though the first voter was @charlietfl